# Vectorize Double Loop - MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I have a double loop, which is very inefficient.

```
c is a [400,2000] matrix
r is a [2000,1] matrix
P is a [2000,1] matrix
S is a [1, 400] matrix


for i=1:400
    for k=1:2000
        c(i,k) = r(k,1) * max([0, P(k,1) - S(1,i)]);
    end
end
```

I tried to make a parfor and it worked. But I was looking for a more elegant solution. I have been trying and trying but no luck...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are only doing element-wise operations, as `-`, and `.*`, this calls for a solution using [`bsxfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

Use

```
bsxfun(@minus,P,S)
```

to do an element-wise subtraction `P(k,1) - S(1,i)`. The output will be a `[2000,400]` matrix. You can apply the `max(0,...)` operation on this matrix, and finally use `bsxfun` again to multiplicate each row by the corresponding `r`:

```
bsxfun(@times,max(bsxfun(@minus,P,S),0),r)
```

As your `c` should be of size `[400,2000]`, add a final transpose operation, and you're finished.

```
c = bsxfun(@times,max(bsxfun(@minus,P,S),0),r).';
```

---

A small time comparison: the for loop takes

```
Elapsed time is 0.688408 seconds.
```

while the `bsxfun` solution only takes

```
Elapsed time is 0.007884 seconds.
```

which is a nice speed-up of 87 for the exact same results.

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you very much.